# Why does this Timer/RunLoop code work? It shouldn’t

Tags: ios, swift, nsrunloop

```
class A: Timer {
    var myTimer: Timer!
}

class TimerTestViewController: UIViewController {
    var a = A()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        a.myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerRun), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.current.add(a, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)

        a.myTimer.fire()
    }
}
```

Notice in `RunLoop.current.add(a, forMode: .common)` that i didn't add `a.myTimer` to runloop but “accidentally” added `a` to the runloop.

why does this code work at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scheduledTimer` has already added the `Timer` to a `RunLoop` and that's why the next line is not even necessary.

See [`Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer)

> Creates a timer and schedules it on the current run loop in the default mode.

The second line passes with `a` only because you have declared `A` to be a `Timer` which is probably an error:

```
// A should not be a Timer!
class A: Timer {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're very, very kind